# JavaScript Replace with incrementation

Tags: javascript, replace

I use `.replace(/([0-9])/, '$1' + 1);` for string for replace number to number + 1, but doesn't work, I know it's string and integer, but how to this in JS?

Comment: that would evaluate as `.replace(/([0-9])/, '$11');` which is probably not what you want, you'd need to use a function to perform the replacement that you're after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot perform math inside a replacement string.

Instead, you need to pass a callback function:

```
.replace(/0-9/, function(m) { return parseInt(m, 10) + 1; })
```

Comment: `/\d/` to be even more concise, not sure if OP would want the `g` flag on there either.